# pydev unresolved import, but code runs on Idle

Tags: python-3.6, pydev

I'm trying to write a simple GUI for a graphing program I am writing, it runs in Idle(Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32) with no problems, but when I try to run in Eclipse, pydev, the script doesn't work.

I opened the console in eclipse and tried to import FigureCanvas(the only error eclipse is showing me) and I got this is the error message I get:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 198, in <module>
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, __version__, __version_info__
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.1.0.201902031515\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.1.0.201902031515\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import (
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.1.0.201902031515\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 18, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.1.0.201902031515\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.1.0.201902031515\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.1.0.201902031515\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 201, in <module>
    "Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5,\n"
ImportError: Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5,
PySide or PySide2 package to be installed, but it was not found.
```

this is the part of the code that is being run, both on idle(which works) and on eclipse(doesn't work)
    # mplwidget.py
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

this is the main function that calles the mpwidget

```
# ------------------------------------------------------
# ---------------------- main.py -----------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)

import numpy as np
import random

class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        loadUi("UI.ui",self)

        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 & Matplotlib Example GUI")

        #self.pushButton_generate_random_signal.clicked.connect(self.update_graph)

        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.MplWidget.canvas, self))


    def update_graph(self):

        fs = 500
        f = random.randint(1, 100)
        ts = 1/fs
        length_of_signal = 100
        t = np.linspace(0,1,length_of_signal)

        cosinus_signal = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
        sinus_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, cosinus_signal)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, sinus_signal)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.legend(('cosinus', 'sinus'),loc='upper right')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_title('Cosinus - Sinus Signal')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()


app = QApplication([])
window = MatplotlibWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

when I try to run the code in eclipse nothing happens, but whe it runs on idle every thing opens the way I expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that some environment variable is not configured the same way in both environments.

Please take a look at the FAQ: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#MyProgramDoesNotWorkInPyDev to see how to proceed (mainly print the environment/PYTHONPATH on both to check the differences and fix the config on PyDev).